# UIDateTime Picker without minutes and seconds in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uidatepicker

How to make UIDateTimePicker with only Date and hour and am/pm.(NO MINUTES OR SECONDS TO DISPLAY !)

Comment: You want to modify UI of UIDateTimePicker right?

Comment: Yes, I tried  setting format as @"dd:mm:yy hh a".  But still it displays minutes in picker.

Comment: Then you can use https://github.com/attias/AADatePicker

Comment: You have to customize Date picker

Answer (score 2):

Change the mode of the `DatePicker` from the storyboard. Find attached screenshot.
[image: Change date picker mode]

```
    NSDate * date = picker.date;
    NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
   [df setDateFormat:@"d:hh a"];
   NSLog(@"picker time: %@", [df stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]);
```

Here picker is the IBoutlet reference for `UIDatePicker`.

Comment: Hey, I can print and fetch it anyways, I hust dn want the user let select minute. So i just want that there should be no minute component in picker. Time picking should just be limited to date and hours.

Answer (score 0):

```
_datepicker.datePickerMode= UIDatePickerModeDate;
[_datepicker reloadInputViews];
```